# WordPress WP-Admin Just Partly blank. Only Left Sidebar shown

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I've been using wordpress for a few years without issues.  No changes in themes or plugins, and lately I lost the ability to see my wp-admin page fully (Only left sidebar shows, right framelayout is completely blank in every sidebar link I click). The website is still fully functioning and works and I'm able to log-in to the admin page (wp-login.php).

The ONLY pages I can see that loads up is Jetpack, Slideshows, and Feedbacks, Settings -> Portfolio SlideShows Pro/Sharing links.

I've tried:

- renaming plugins to deactivate
- renaming template (retromania) and uploading twentyeleven
- reloaded 'backwpup' auto backup files even all the way back to 2013-7-13-53-23.
- Checking functions.php page for empty blanks top and bottom
- rewrite wp-config Akismet Key
- Attempted to turn on 'WP-Debug', but have no idea where the log goes...

---

Here is what my error_log says from my /wp/ folder:

[27-Jun-2014 04:06:17 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home2/wesleych/public_html/wp/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in /home2/wesleych/public_html/wp/wp-settings.php on line 21
-- repeated 2 more times--

[27-Jul-2014 16:01:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home2/wesleych/public_html/wp/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2911
-- repeated 9 more times --

[27-Jul-2014 16:02:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home2/wesleych/public_html/wp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 461
-- repeated 8 more times --

[20-Sep-2014 15:34:16 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function force_ssl_admin() in /home2/wesleych/public_html/wp/wp-login.php on line 15

[20-Sep-2014 21:47:57 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: backwpup_int in /home2/wesleych/public_html/wp/wp-includes/cron.php on line 103

---

I've been scowering the web for some similar issues, seems like all places I looked only talks about completely blank wp-admin pages.

Any suggestions? =)

Comment: Have you tried update your wordpress and plugins ?

Comment: which version of word press you are using?

Comment: Hi Khsushboo and Ram.  I'm not sure what version I am running.  (How do I find out?)  I do know there is a (1) beside my Update tab, so I figure I'm not at the latest update.

Comment: it's 2017 and I'm having the same issues just like the OP. Scoured the web almost nothing on solving this.

Comment: @dtechplus Run into something similar; this issue's likely because some files in wp-includes are not being loaded. You can try to replace the wp-includes folder (after doing a backup of course) with one from a fresh WP install of the same version. All the errors above are related to a file in that folder not being loaded

Comment: @kakoma that was exactly what I did! Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but still relevant.

I had the same issue and fixed it with WP CLI.

From the root of WP, where `wp-config.php`, `wp-includes`, and `wp-admin` are, run the following command to reinstall WP.
**It's very important to run it from the root of the WP install!**.

```
wp core download --force --skip-content --locale=en_US --version=6.2
```

Replace the `--version=6.2` with the version of WP you are using on your site.
You can also install the latest version instead:

```
wp core update
```

After the installation is done run:

```
wp core update-db
```

That should clean up the WP files and fix the problem if is related to the installation.

In the end, you might want to update the current theme and all plugins.